# AzureDevOps Forecast lines cannot be drawn

Tags: azure-devops, forecasting, scrum

AzureDevOps is returning the following "Error" when I turn on forecasting for my backlog.

Based on the velocity you have entered, the first item on your backlog cannot be completed in the remaining iterations. I have 200 hours of capacity in each sprint, out of which about 120 is development hours. The effort is being populated in hours, not in figurative numbers. The first item in the backlog is a bug, with 16 hours of development work remaining.

[AzureDevOps Forecasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGyQf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By plugging in a value for the [team velocity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops), the forecast tool will show which items in the backlog can be completed within future sprints. You need to change the velocity value, as there is no items can be completed with the velocity you entered.

Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/forecast?view=azure-devops